# Proving a parametrized function cannot generically cover a curve

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, transversality

Let $D$ be a set of infinitely smooth (in $C^\infty$) functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that are strictly increasing in both arguments. Let $C$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$  and $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \times C \to \mathbb{R}$ be some twice-continuously differentiable function strictly increasing in the first two arguments. $C$ is its parameter space.

I want to show that the following property holds for a generic $f\in D$:

*For every $k\in \mathbb{R}$, $x \in C$, the set
$
\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2: \ \ g(a,b; x)= f(a,b)=k \}
$ is countable.*

By `generically' I mean that it holds on an open and dense set of functions $f$ in $D$.

**Intuition:** The parameter space of $g$ is finite-dimensional. Thus, there are not enough degrees of freedom to align the level curves of $f$ and $g$ along any region of positive length.

Infinite dimentional Thom's transversality theorem seems relevant, but I do not know how to apply it.

Comment: What does strictly increasing mean in this case?

Comment: The function takes in two real arguments, so strictly increasing in each of them.

Comment: You should add this information to your question.

Comment: Done, thank you!